# Will a Kafka JDBC source connector resolve /etc/hosts?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

When providing the `connection.url` for a source connector, I pass an IP address as part of the JDBC connection string. However, this IP is not static all the time, as the source system will be migrated soon.

Two questions arise:

- does the connector support DNS names, so we can move away from IPs in the connection string?
- does the JDBC connector resolve the IP, if we put it in /etc/hosts mapped to another hostname and change the host in the connection string accordingly? This suggestion came up during some discussions, but I have quite some doubts about that solution.

Comment: Yes, it should support because Java `InetAddress` does DNS resolution. Isn't it working for you? In case, if it doesn't you can post the relevant error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is passing the DNS resolution to the OS, so the framework doesn't control that.

The `/etc/hosts` file is also static, however, so you might want to look at other service-discovery options such as HashiCorp Consul.

Comment: Yes, it's static but we can easily update the file as part of a rollout pipeline whenever necessary to keep the connector and its offset. I know it's also possible to update a connector on-the-fly using the Connect API (we could also do that within a pipeline), but I'd feel more safe using a simple file write than GET connector, modify JSON and PUT connector in a productive environment, especially when automated.

Comment: Keep in mind that the JVM has a DNS cache, so modifying the hosts file might not work (immediately)